# What form does a Taylor series general term need to be in? Why don't my general term equation give me the first term sometimes?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

So this is written in my book for Taylor series:

[image]

Most importantly, I notice that the exponent after $(x-a)$, and the factorial, and the n that currently being iterated over are all equal.

To demonstrate my confusion, let's look at the Taylor series for $ln(1+x)$ and $xe^{-2x}$.

so:

$$f'(x) = \frac{1}{x+1},\quad f''(x) = \frac{-1}{(x+1)^2},\quad
f'''(x) = \frac{2}{(x+1)^3},\quad f^{(4)}(x) = \frac{-6}{(x+1)^4}$$
and

$$f'(0) = 1, \ f''(0) = -2,\ f'''(0) = 2, \ 
f^{(4)}(0) = -6
$$

so notice the general term starts at $n = 1$ but the exponent to x is only n. Is this a problem?

so $$
\ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{n!} x^n
= x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}$$

So the general term here seems to accurate represent the Taylor series even though the n term doesn't match up with the exponent term for x.

However, $xe^{-2x}$ is different:

so finding the Taylor series form:
we know that $e^x$ is: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$. 
So
$$e^{2x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2x)^n}{n!}, \
e^{-2x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-2x)^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^nx^n}{n!},\ 
xe^{-2x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^nx^{n+1}}{n!}$$

So according to the formula, the first term is just f(a) which should equal the general formula when I plug in n = 0 right? But theres a mismatch. When I plug in n = 0, I get $x$. But f(0) = 0. So what gives? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You shouldn't be concerned about matching. Simplifying by multiplying out terms will affect the index of summation and how it's expressed in summation notation, but how a Taylor Series is derived stays the same. You're getting too worked up by the notation.

Comment: do my answers look right?

Comment: What do you mean by "plug in $n=0$? You should "plug in $a=0$".

Comment: Note that $f''(0) = -1$ not $-2$. Also, your question is hard to read really. Could you please make it simpler and very focused? You know the general term...so what exactly is the question?

Comment: @Jack I plug in n = 0 because that's what $t_0$ is which should = f(a) right?

Comment: @NoChance the question is essentiall why don't my general form equations give me the first term sometimes?

Comment: Try to actually use the rule in your textbook to compute the series of $\ln(1+x)$. Then compare with the series quoted. Your confusion isn't something that can be easily cleared up by someone else. You just need to either see it or not.

Comment: @Jwan622: No. That is incorrect. See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me repeat your question in a concise way.

> Let $f(x)=\ln (1+x)$ and $a=0$. On the one hand, formula (6) you quoted form the book says that the $0$-th term of the Taylor series should be $f(a)=f(0)=\ln(1+0)=0$. On the other hand, one has
>   $$
> \ln(1+x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{n!} x^n
> = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots\tag{1}
> $$
>   The term $x$ in (1) does not match the $0$-th term in the formula (6), what is going wrong?

It is not that there is mismatch but that you match the formulas in a **wrong** way. The equality in (1) could be written as

$$
\ln(1+x) = \color{blue}{ 0 +} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{n!} x^n
= \color{blue} {0+}x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}+\cdots\tag{2}
$$

And (2) "matches" formula (6):
$$
f(0)=0\;,\  f'(0)=(-1)^{\color{red}{1}-1}(\color{red}{1}-1)!=1\;,\\
f''(0)=(-1)^{\color{red}{2}-1}(\color{red}{2}-1)!=-1\;,\\ 
f'''(0)=(-1)^{\color{red}{3}-1}(\color{red}{3}-1)!=2!\;,\\
\vdots
$$

---

Now, let us look at another Taylor series you mentioned in your post:
$$
g(x)=xe^{-2x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^nx^{n+1}}{n!}\tag{3}
$$
Again, what confuses you is that $g(0)=0$, which should be the $0$-th term in the Taylor series, but for $n=0$, the term in (3) is $x$.

The problem is that the $n$ in (3) is NOT the same as the $n$ in (6)!!

---

In general, if
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n,
$$ 
one can **not** conclude that $a_n=b_n$.

---

**Exercise**. Find the Taylor series for the function $f(x)=x^3$ at $a=0$ using formula (6) and see how your result "matches" the "general formula".

Comment: Very neat presentation indeed. Thank you.